# Proof that an automorphism of an extension field of $\mathbb Q$ fixes rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

At [this point of the lecture](https://youtu.be/dZxZTKX3-bU?t=4m36s) on field automorphisms by Professor Macauley, the proof that an automorphism, $\phi,$ on an extension field $F$ of $\mathbb Q$ fixes the rational numbers, i.e.

$$\phi(q)=q\quad\quad\quad  \forall \; q \in \mathbb Q$$

is given for the number $1,$ asserting that if $\phi(1)=q,$ $q$ can't be $0$ since, if it were,

$$\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=0$$

and $\phi(\dot)$ would not be a bijection.

Likewise, since

$$q=\phi(1)=\phi(1\cdot1)=\phi(1)\cdot\phi(1)=q^2$$

and

$$q=\phi(1)=\phi(1\cdot1\cdot 1)=\phi(1)\cdot\phi(1)\cdot\phi(1)=q^3$$

we have to conclude that $\phi(1)=1.$

This is clear, but the question is

> How does this proof generalize to the rest of rational numbers 
>   $$\phi(n)=n;\;n>1,n=\frac{a}{b}; \, a,b\in \mathbb Q?$$

Comment: A field automorphism takes sums to sums, differences to differences, products to products, and quotients to quotients. In particular,
$$\phi\left({\small{\frac{a}{b}}}\right) = {\small{\frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(b)}}}$$

Comment: $\phi(n)=\phi(1+\cdots +1)=\phi(1)+\cdots +\phi(1)=1+\cdots +1=n$.

Comment: Hint. Use induction to prove it fixes every  positive integer. Then since it preserves rules of arithmetic it preserves subtraction and division, hence all rationals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that field automorphisms respect addition, multiplication, and inverses. Hence, it is enough to check that $1$ is fixed.

for $n \in \mathbb N$,

$\phi(n)=\phi(1) + \cdots \phi(1)=1+ \dots+1=n$, where each sum is adding $n$ times.

For $n \in \mathbb Q$,

$\phi(n)=\phi(ab^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(b^{-1})=\phi(a) \phi(b)^{-1}=ab^{-1}$.

To see that $\phi(b^{-1})=\phi(b)^{-1}$, note that $1=\phi(1)=\phi(bb^{-1})=\phi(b)\phi(b^{-1}) \implies \phi(b)^{-1}=\phi(b^{-1})$

Comment: Thank you. I'll come back to accept it later on - give it a chance to accrue some upvotes besides mine...

Comment: @AntoniParellada the question was closed as a duplicate. No need to worry about upvotes :). Do you understand the idea?

Comment: Crystal clear. Thanks, again! (I think the answer can be upvoted independently - I did).